# How to insert bulk document into elastic using PowerShell?

Tags: json, powershell, api, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to read the data from CSV file which has 2200000 records using PowerShell and storing each record in JSON file as NDJSON format.

Total document in JSON file is 2200000 (200 MB)

**Sample JSON Data**

```json
{"index":{}}
{"ip-address":"1.5.0.1","is-vpn":"true","@timestamp":"2022-12-01T18:59:48.8325021+05:30"}
{"index":{}}
{"ip-address":"243.11.0.1","is-vpn":"true","@timestamp":"2022-12-01T18:59:48.8853225+05:30"}
{"index":{}}
{"ip-address":"253.11.0.1","is-vpn":"true","@timestamp":"2022-12-01T18:59:48.8853225+05:30"}
{"index":{}}
{"ip-address":"39.24.0.1","is-vpn":"true","@timestamp":"2022-12-01T18:59:48.8853225+05:30"}
{"index":{}}
{"ip-address":"163.24.0.1","is-vpn":"true","@timestamp":"2022-12-01T18:59:48.8853225+05:30"}
```

**Code**

```
function Get-IPDataPath
{
    $dbFilePath = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootDir -Filter "IP2*.CSV" | ForEach-Object FullName | Select-Object -First 1
    Write-Host "file path - $dbFilePath"
    $dbFilePath  # implicit output
}

function Convert-NumberToIP
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$number
    )

    [Int64] $numberInt = 0
    if( [Int64]::TryParse( $number, [ref] $numberInt ) ) {
        if( ($numberInt -ge 0) -and ($numberInt -le 0xFFFFFFFFl) ) {
            # Convert to IP address like '192.168.23.42'
            ([IPAddress] $numberInt).ToString()
        }
    }
    # In case TryParse() returns $false or the number is out of range for an IPv4 address, 
    # the output of this function will be empty, which converts to $false in a boolean context.
}

function Insert-Document
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$indexName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][object]$filePath
    )

    $url = "https://esdev2:9200/naveen/_doc/_bulk"
    $encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($cred))
    $headers = @{
                    "Authorization" = "Basic $encodedCreds"
                    "Transfer-Encoding" = "chunked"
                    "Content-Type" = "application/x-ndjson"
                }
    $content = Get-Content -Path $filepath
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method POST -Body $content -Headers $Headers -ContentType 'application/x-ndjson'

    if($response.StatusCode -eq 201)
    {
        Write-Host "Documents added successfully"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host $response
        Write-Host "$($response.content)"
        throw "Trouble adding document: $_"
    }
}

$dbFilePath = Get-IPDataPath
$outputFile = Join-Path -Path $rootDir -ChildPath "output.json"

Write-Host "Converting CSV file $dbFilePath to $outputFile"

$object = [PSCustomObject]@{
    'ip-address' = ''
    'is-vpn' = 'true'
    '@timestamp' = ''
}

# Enclose foreach loop in a script block to be able to pipe its output to Set-Content

$count = 0
& {
    foreach( $item in [Linq.Enumerable]::Skip( [IO.File]::ReadLines( $dbFilePath ), 1 ) )
    {
        $row = $item -split ','
        $ipNumber = $row[0].trim('"')

        if( $ip = Convert-NumberToIP -number $ipNumber ) 
        {
            $index = [PSCustomObject]@{"index" = [PSCustomObject]@{}} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 -Compress
                $object.'ip-address' = $ip
                $object.'@timestamp' = (Get-Date).ToString('o')
                #$index | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 -Compress
                $document = $object | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 -Compress

                if($count -lt 25)
                {
                    Add-Content -Path $outputFile $index
                    Add-Content -Path $outputFile $document
                    $count++
                }
                else
                {
                    $count = 0
                    BulkInsert-Document -indexName $indexName -filePath $outputFile
                    Clear-Content -Path $outputFile
                }
        }

    }
} | Set-Content -Path $outputFile

Write-Host "Inserting document in elastic"
Insert-Document -indexName $indexName -filePath $outputFile
```

But I am getting **Error: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The bulk
request must be terminated by a newline
[\n]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The bulk request must be
terminated by a newline [\n]"},"status":400}**

Though I have new line at the end of JSON file, Could you please help how to insert all the document.

Comment: I see two issues 1) A good response is 200 (not 201). 2) You are down loading data.  You request has no body.  So you should be doing a GET (not POST).  A post is when the body contains a body.  I think the error is due to the body being empty.  Since you do not have a body then use GET.

Comment: Hey @jdweng I am using json file as body where all the records are there.

Comment: The body should be a string not a filename.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3#-body

Comment: @jdweng tried but getting `The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity 
Too Large.`

Comment: @jdweng tried with 20 records getting same error `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The bulk 
request must be terminated by a newline 
[\\n]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The bulk request must be 
terminated by a newline [\\n]"},"status":400}`

Comment: You need to set the Content-Length : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/the-bulk-request-must-be-terminated-by-a-newline/280403/2

Comment: @jdweng but I am using powershell also updated the code, please check updated question code it's taking long time

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is powershell or any other language.  The request looks the same to the server.  You need to add the http header Content-Length.  Right now you have two headers Authorization and ContentType.  You need a third header Content-Length.

Comment: Tried with `Content-Length and also with "Transfer-Encoding" = "chunked"` not working.

Comment: You probably have more than one issue.  You still have the -body as the pathname instead of the contents of the file.  The content length must be the size of the content.  Chunked is HTTP version 1.1 while the default is usually stream mode version 1.0. The error doesn't indicated that is has anything to do with chunked mode.

Comment: I have updated the `function Insert-Document` with which I had tried.

Comment: Try something simple : $content = (Get-Content -Path $filepath) + "\n" Previously you only had the filename.